# Joining Model with Table Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have created a model in Laravel.

```
class deals extends Model
{
//
protected $table = 'tbl_deal';
}
```

Now I want to use this model to retrieve data in my Controller. However, the data extracted from this model also needs to be constrained by a column in another table. Below is the basic schema

**tbl_deal**

- deal_id
- merchant_id
- deal_text

**tbl_merchant**

- merchant_id
- merchant_url_text

My current Controller has the following code to extract all deals from deals model.

```
$deals = deals::all();
```

I want to constraint the deals by merchant_url_text. Since that is in merchant table, I would need to join it with the existing deal model.

Any help on how I can do that in my controller and if this is the right way to solve this kind of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `deals` model

the following function (called [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)):

```
public function merchant()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class, merchant_id);
}
```

and now you will be able to get all deals with merchant using

```
$deals = deals::with('merchant')->get();
```

For example to display the first one use:

```
$deal = $deals->first();
echo $deal->merchant->merchant_url_text;
```

However to use this you need to create also `Merchant` model and using this method no `join` will be used.

In case you want to use simple join instead of relationship in this case, you can use:

```
$deals = deals::selectRaw('tbl_deal.*, tbl_merchant.merchant_url_text')
              ->leftJoin('tbl_merchant','tbl_deal.merchant_id','=','table_merchant.merchant_id')->get();
```

And now to display 1st merchant text you can use:

```
$deal = $deals->first();
echo $deal->merchant_url_text;
```

I strongly recommend to read Laravel documentation to fully understand basic Laravel concepts before writing any code (for example by convention model name should be `Deal` instead of `deals` and table name should be `deals` instead of `tbl_deal`, similar for primary key - it should be simple `id` instead of `deal_id`).

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Going through the documentation in detail.

Comment: Just a quick query. If I have to constraint the response of deals based on a specific variable that i have in my controller (in this case merchant_url_text), how do I do it?