# How to joins table in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this table in Laravel Framework:

**profiles table:**

[image]

I want to fill up `userID` column when any user creates a profile. For this I am trying to code something like this:

**Profile model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userID');
}
```

**And User model:**

```
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Profile');
}
```

In this way it keeps `null` value every time. How can I solve this?

Comment: check this [joining-model-with-table-laravel-5-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423319/joining-model-with-table-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inserting Data into Profile Table, you just need to do as follows:

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->userID = Auth::user()->id;
$profile->other_columns = 'values'
.....
$profile->save();
```

There is no need to join the tables for inserting the value in Profile Table for here. Hope this helps you

Comment: Now i understand.Accepted.

Comment: Great :) I'm happy that it helped you

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you have the following (which you kind of do)

```
public function profiles()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class); // we do not need to provide the user_id because laravel assume we are using that
}

<?php
// Profile.php (Model)

public function user()
{
  $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class); // Again we do not need to provide the information because of the table / column names we are using
}
```

You have a few options, you can either when creating the profile, assign the user_id (as long as it is in the fillable fields.

```
$profile = new Profile;
$profile->user_id = \Auth::getId(); // current logged in user
$profile->somethingElse = 'abc';
$profile->save();
```

Or since we have a relationship you should be able to do something like this

```
$profile = new Profile;
$profile->somethingElse = 'abc';
// We will use the current logged in user again
Auth::user()->profiles()->save($profile); // will automagically fill in the user_id with the logged in user's id.
```

Hopefully that sheds some light

Comment: both are giving me error...First one giving me "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'getId'" AND second one ""Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Comment: are you sure those two function belongsTo each other?

Comment: You can change them to a hasOne if needed... If the relationship isn't working you can use the 1st suggestion where you assign the "user_id" because calling a save()